# How can I add a list to a user in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app I'm building.

Right now the database looks like this.

[image: Right now the database looks like this.]

I want to add to each of the users (When they first sign in) another field name "friends" and hold a list in there.
How can I do it?

I want it to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first child of "users" is userId.

You can add "friends" child to it like this.

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child( currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends").setValue("your First Friend");
```

after that you implement these methods on that child like this.

```
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

Read docs of firebase [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Comment: Hi, the last line gives me an error. It says cannot resolve symbol getUid. And if i change it to getUid() it says incompatible type
Required : .....databeserefernce Found: .....tasks.Task

Comment: Sorry its getUid ()

Comment: Check if current user is null or not before taking database reference. Above code must work.

Answer (score 0):

If the getUid is getting trobule, try to see if it is not null or if is equal in the database. if is correct, transform it into a private string and put in the DatabaseReference.

```
String userKey = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child( userKey).child("friends").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               String value = datasnapshot.getValue(String.class);
      //verifiy if has something in the friendList and put value if has
             if(value != null) { 
              myRef.setValue("My new FRRIIIEEEND);
 }

};
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
```

i think it should help you this code

Answer (score 0):

Usually when i need to store a list, i do it by using the `List<>` from `java.util`. If you use something called **`GenericTypeIndicator`**, you can directly input your custom java objects to be automatically serialized into the Firebase Database.

Let's say your "friends" list is a collection of `User` objects. I would do something like this:

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child( currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends");
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         GenericTypeIndicator<List<User>> genericTypeIndicator =new GenericTypeIndicator<List<User>>(){};
         List<User> friends = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);
         // Check if friends list exists
         if(friends == null){
             // Create list
             friends = new ArrayList<User>();
         }
         // Add new user
         friends.add(youUserHere);

         // Set updated friends list
         database.getReference("users").child( currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends").setValue(friends);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```